# Request.getParameter() replacing ONLY "+" for " "

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, encoding

I'm facing a problem when trying to retrieve parameters on backend.

I know that there are some reserved chars on URLs. But I have some already written LINKS that contains "+" "@", etc on it links.

Ex: www.server.com/?param=@a+b

At the backend, req.getParameter("param") returns "@a b" instead of "@a+b". Is there a workaround for this case that the "client" is already sending "+" chars to server?

I'm using App Engine on Flexible Environment with Jetty servlet container.

Maybe the answer that I'm looking for it what is the charset that makes "+" being replaced by " " and @ don't.

Comment: You can call `getQueryString()` and parse it however you like.

Comment: Good idea. It can de done. But is there other way?

Comment: Not directly relevant for your question, but as a related matter, although Tomcat does not support special handling of the **+** character in query strings, it does for eleven others: **" < > [ \ ] ^ ` { | }**. [See the **relaxedQueryChars** attribute specification for **Connector** elements in **server.xml**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). I don't know about Jetty and other application servers, but they might do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your existing predefined links, if you want the plus sign to be preserved in your query string on the server then simply replace each occurrence in the query string of **+** with **%2B**.

For example, instead of 
**www.server.com/?param=@a+b** 
use 
**www.server.com/?param=@a%2Bb**

If you do that then:

- `request.getQueryString()` will return "**param=@a%2Bb**" (i.e. the raw value).
- `request.getParameter("param")` will return "**@a+b**" which is presumably what you want.

Obviously this is not a general purpose solution where you have no control over the URLs which get submitted, and how they are submitted, but I verified it using several different browsers, Postman and curl.

Also, users usually want and expect a plus character in their query string to be translated to a space, but the change suggested above does not impede that in any way.